# Increase Node Distance in Kamada Kawai Layout

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to visualise a graph a bit like a tree graph, but it's not strictly speaking a tree graph.
It looks like this:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTqLQ.png)

I would like to have the general structure as it is, but space the nodes that are in one layer further away from each other so they don't overlap.

I'm using the `pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G, scale=1)` command to create the node positions. I have found that the `scale` parameter doesn't change anything.

How can I stop nodes from overlapping and spread them out in general?

Comment: Can you share the result of `G.edges(data=True)`?

Comment: You could probably go with a graphviz layout. Here's a similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61211457/9698684

Comment: thats the solution, it works perfectly: https://imgur.com/zL3McaS
thank you so much!